# TypeScript - trying to call a function through props. ERROR - x is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi i have a dashboard that calls out to a seperate file to generate notifcations.

with the notification i have an x button to dismiss the notification which calls through props to a function which removes that notification from the data array.

But whenever i try to call the function by pressing the X i get an error stating the function in the dashboard file is not a function.

```
handleNotification = (index: number)   => {
    console.log("notification" , index, "clicked")
    TempData.splice(index, 1);

  }


 // this.props.divSelected controls the functionality to open cert tabe in correct DIV
  render() {    
    const globalProps = {
      notifications: TempData,
      handleNotification: this.handleNotification
    }
```

this is the dashboard code

```
   interface Props {
  notifications: Array<object>
  handleNotification: (index:number) => void
}

function GenerateMap(data: any, props:Props): JSX.Element {  
  return(
    data.notifications.map((element: { type: string; message: string, }, i: number) => {
    return (
      <div key={i} className={element.type}>{element.message}<button onClick={() => { props.handleNotification(i) }}></button></div>
      )
  }))
  
}
```

this is the notification code.

```
<GenerateNotification {...globalProps}/>
```

this is how i pass the props from the dashboard code into the notificaion file.

the only thing i can think of is the this function goes through a seperate const Y that calls upon this function within the file.

but only const Y is exported ??

thanks in advance

Comment: How do you pass `globalProps` to `GenerateMap` in your render function?

Comment: updated to include requested code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the issue i had was that i was trying to callback to a function through props from within a const function and not a class.

as soon as i changed the const function into a class everything worked.